# How can I mine a block, in C#, on a new Testnet network where no other miners exist?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-reward, testnet, nbitcoin

I want to demonstrate how to use NBitcoin or the most simple C# function to

- collect transactions for use in a block
- then sign that block
- submit it into the Bitcoin-QT network client on the RPC port?

I want to demonstrate how this is done on low powered devices.

Comment: You can use NBitcoin test framework with regtest: https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin.Docs/blob/master/P2P.md

Comment: Thanks @prayank though can you help me find how to offload the computation of the SHA Hash of a block, and then where it assembles the special "mining transaction block"

Comment: Sorry I have no clue. Maybe you can ask new [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Prayank I don't want to ask a new question for the one that I already posted, above...